# Chaincode shim: more values for a key or allowing non-integer in the value

Tags: hyperledger

During the chaincode init, One can deploy key-value pair such as: ["a","100", "b", "200"]

However, I would like to deploy key-value pairs such as: ["a", "100, v1, v2"]
Such that 100, v1, v2 are values of a. Two notes:
1. The values are non-integer
2. The values are separated by comma ","

Is this possible?

I check the chaincode shim: /home/standards/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go

The function:

```
// PutState writes the specified `value` and `key` into the ledger.
func (stub *ChaincodeStub) PutState(key string, value []byte) error {
    return handler.handlePutState(key, value, stub.UUID)
```

Which invokes handlePutState (key, value, stub.UUID). Any lights on how to modify it so it works as desired? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chaincode, each state can have only a single value associated with it. However multiple values can be simulated by making that "one value" a list. So you could do something like this

```
stub.PutState("a",[]byte("100,v1,v2"))
```

The state for "a" is now a comma separated list. When you want to retrieve these values, do the following:

```
Avals, err := stub.GetState("a")
AvalsString := string(Avals)
fmt.Println(AvalsString)
```

which should print the following string

> 100,v1,v2

If you need the individual arguments from there, just split the string on the commas, and convert to appropriate types. Bam, you can store and retrieve elements now.

Alternatively, if you data structure is more complicated than that, it might be worth it to put your data into a json object. You can then use marshaling and unmarshaling to convert back and forth from `[]byte` (which can be stored in the state directly) and object (which is likely easier to use).

Example with Json, using init method because it's the one you mentioned

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    AVal   string            `json:"Aval"`
    BVal   []string            `json:"Bval"`
}

func (t *MyChaincode) Init(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
    //recieve args ["someStringA","BVal1","Bval2","Bval3"]

    //constructing and storing json object
    myStruct := SomeStruct{
        AVal: args[0],
        BVal: []string{args[1],args[2],args[3]},
    }
    myStructBytes, err := json.Marshal(myStruct)
    _ = err //ignore errors for example
    stub.PutState("myStructKey",myStructBytes)

    //get state back to object
    var retrievedStruct SomeStruct
    retrievedBytes, err := stub.GetState("myStructKey")
    json.Unmarshal(retrievedBytes,retrievedStruct)

    //congratulations, retrievedStruct now contains the data you stored earlier
    return nil,nil
}
```